Does equilibrium always exist for a conductor in an arbitrary electric field?
I clearly understand the well-known fact that in equilibrium there is no electric field inside a conductor because if there were, free charges would move, which contradicts the definition of equilibrium. From Gauss's law, it can also be derived that the charge density inside the conductor is zero, meaning only surface charges exist. My question is: why does such a surface charge distribution which cancels any field inside the conductor always exist? I understand that for simple cases, such as a conducting sphere placed in a uniform electric field, we can explicitly determine this distribution. But what if we consider a conductor of arbitrary shape placed in an arbitrary electric field? Is there any way to prove that equilibrium always exists in such cases? Or is there a counterexample showing that equilibrium may never be achieved because it simply does not exist?

How can a state of equilibrium not exist? Any non-equilibrium state will change with time until it reaches equilibrium. I agree that it is far from obvious how charge would be distributed on some random surface, but that equilibrium distribution must exist because the alternative is that the charge distribution changes with time forever.

@JohnRennie, I see that if there is no equilibrium, the distribution will continue changing indefinitely. However, I see no contradiction here. For example, if we place a charged particle in a uniform magnetic field with an initial velocity, it will move in a circular path forever and will never reach equilibrium. Why can't something similar happen in a conductor?

Because there is always resistance in a conductor so energy is continuously being dissipated as heat. Even in a superconductor the acceleration of the electrons would dissipate energy by radiating EM waves. So the electrons cannot move indefinitely without violating conservation of energy.

@JohnRennie, you're right: if the system is conservative, any movement will eventually stop. However, let's consider placing a conductor of an arbitrary shape in a constant electric field. Of course, as charges move, energy is dissipated, but this energy doesn't appear out of nowhere because work is done to maintain the constant field. In this case, there is no contradiction if the electrons move permanently (unless equilibrium does indeed exist). Are there any mistakes in my reasoning?

It is a bit obscure to me what your question really is about, so let me rephrase. There is a math problem to find a $\phi$ that satisfies $\nabla^2\phi=0$ in an otherwise unbounded 3D domain that are bounded by a finite set of closed smooth surfaces $\mathcal S_k;,k=1,2,..,M$ and $\phi[{\mathcal S_k}]=V_k=\mathrm{const}$ and $\lim _{R\to \infty}\nabla \phi(x,y,z) = \mathrm{prescribed}; R=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. This PDE problem can be solved and has a unique solution under rather broad smoothness conditions.

An equilibrium distribution of charges is one that does not change. It must create an electric field that exerts no forces on itself. Such a field must be $0$ in the interior and perpendicular to the surface at the surface.
Suppose you have a non-equilibrium field. There must be a non-$0$ field in the interior or a component parallel to the surface. If such a field is from left to right, there must be an excess of + on the left and/or - on the right. Electrons will flow toward the + and away from the -. This reduces the field.
So a non-equilibrium field induces changes that make it smaller. This continues until it is gone. A non-equilibrium distribution of charges drives itself to equilibrium.

Say there wasn't any surface charge density distribution for a conductor that $ever$ nullified the external electric field $\vec E$ inside the conductor. At such a point there must always be a non-zero current (density $\vec j$) due to the never decreasing electrical force/drift experienced by the free charges. Charge conservation $^0$ then implies two possible outcomes: either free charges are completely depleted (we are no longer talking about a conductor) or the local charge density $\rho$ becomes arbitrarily large, overtime. But such a large charge density $\rho$ would necessarily produce $^1$ it's own $\vec {E'} $ till such time that it is comparable to the external $\vec E$ (in fact it would be equal and opposite). This contradicts our initial assumption that the external field is unmodified by the motion/redistribution of charges inside the conductor.

$^0$$\partial_t \rho+\vec\nabla.\vec j=0$
$^1$ $\vec\nabla .\vec E \propto \rho$
